# Database extension is accdb when I want it to be mdb

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, ms-access-2010

I am using MS Office 2010. I want to create a `.mdb` database. I looked around but I don't know how to change the default extension.
This database will be used for practicing Java JDBC-ODBC connection and for that I need a `.mdb` database.
Please tell me how to change the default extension.

Comment: You don't need to change it. http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007#microsoft-access-accdb-odbc-driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]When you create a new database, go to
`File` -> `Options` -> `General`, and set the `Default File Format` to `Access 2002-2003`.

Answer (score 4):

In MS Access 2010,

Click on the `File` tab and click the `Save & Publish` option on the left-hand menu.

You'll see that you have the option under `File Types` to choose `Save Database As`

Then under `Save Database As`, you can select different database file types, including: Access 2000 Database (*.mdb) and Access 2002-2003 Database (*.mdb).